# knockout.js pushing items into observablearray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5SF7/3/).

I am trying to push objects for an existing array into a knockout observable array but am failing terrible. How do I get this code to work, and since this code sucks what is the 'proper' way of doing this. Thank you so much

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Bob">
    <div data-bind="text: $data">
    </div>
</div>
var Test = function(){
    var self= this;
    self.Init = function(name){
        self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    };
};
var ArrayOfTests = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.Init = function(tests){
        self.AllTests = ko.observableArray([]);
        for(var i = 0; i <=tests.length-1;i++)
        {
            self.AllTests.push(tests[i]);
        };
    };
};

var TestViewModule = function(){
    self.Bob = ko.observable();
    var temp = new ArrayOfTests();
    var tempTest = new Test();
    tempTest.Init('one2');
    temp.Init([tempTest,tempTest]);
    self.Bob= temp;
};
ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModule());
console.log(new TestViewModule());
```

The answer ended up being, I was adding a null item to the array making the array not work.

Comment: can you just explain what your objective, and please minimize "test" words

Comment: I want to put one array inside of an ko.observableArray

Comment: just read again thee [Observable Arrays documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass 'one2' string in Test.Init, but this method don't accept parameters:

```
var Test = function(){
    var self= this;
    self.Name = ko.observable();
    self.Init = function(data){
        self.Name(data);  
    };
};
```

**Edit**

I completly refactored your viewModel, because current implementation is not correct:

Html:

```
<div data-bind="with: Bob">
    <div data-bind="foreach: AllTests">
       <div data-bind="text: $data">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
var Test = function(){
    var self= this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);

    self.Init = function(name){
        self.Name(name);
    };
};

var ArrayOfTests = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.AllTests = ko.observableArray();

    self.Init = function(tests) {        
        for(var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
            self.AllTests.push(tests[i].Name());
        };
    };
};

var TestViewModule = function(){
    var temp = new ArrayOfTests();
    var tempTest = new Test();
    tempTest.Init('one2');
    temp.Init([tempTest,tempTest]);

    self.Bob = ko.observable(temp);
};

ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModule());
console.log(new TestViewModule());
```

Comment: Cool!!why do you have to push the name of Test, instead of the test object itself? what if the test object had more properties then just the name?

Comment: I thought that's what you want, of course you can push Test and use its observable properties.